Why does a function taking a std::unique_ptr by value not call the destructor in gcc/clang?
Looking at the assembly output of the following simple C++ function:
#include <memory>
int square(std::unique_ptr<int> num) {
    return *num * *num;
}

Gcc and clang emit the following assembly (-O2):
square(std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        imul    eax, eax
        ret

This was very unexpected for me: where is the destructor being  called?
MSVC on the other hand does what I expected, and calls the destructor.
Here's a godbolt repro: https://godbolt.org/z/e66xh9Yos
I also tried using bigger types than int to see if it's some small size optimization,
but that did not seem to be the case.
Can anybody explain what is going on here?

If you add a main, g++ does it on the caller side.

The caller destroys the parameter. I'll tell you more, the parameter (in GCC & Clang at least) seems to live until the end of the full expression calling the function.

Ah! So it's just a difference in calling convention? Thanks a bunch, I probably should have figured that out myself. If your comments were answers I would accept them.

Microsoft's calling convention does the (IMHO) sane thing and lets the called function call by-value argument destructors. Other compilers on Windows such as MinGW and Clang will do the same to be compatible. The SysV calling convention used in Linux, BSD, and Mac (?) lets the caller do the cleanup; probably because the caller is also the one cleaning up the stack. The downside there are that it will replicate the destructor at every call site (lots of code, especially for shared_ptr) and it makes it harder to remove destructor calls after objects have been moved away inside the function

Late destruction of function parameters

It is implementation-defined whether function parameter objects are destroyed at when a function returns or at the end of the full-expression containing the call to the function.
In other words, it is an ABI decision whether or not the caller or the callee is responsible for calling the destructor.
The Itanium C++ ABI (used everywhere except for MSVC as far as I am aware) chooses to destroy function parameter objects at the end of the full-expression containing the call. On the other hand MSVC's ABI chooses to destroy them when the function returns.
The standard made it explicitly implementation-defined to support both of these ABI decisions retroactively.
Also note that calling the constructor for the function parameter object is always responsibility of the caller. So the caller is able to call the destructor just as well as the callee is. It knows where the object has been constructed and what its type is from the function declaration.
